# Backbone Push State In All Browsers

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to use the "push state" routing (i.e. /about instead of #about) in all browsers (even old IE). Nothing would make me happier than if old IE users experiencing a page reload on every click and my routing is setup such that loading up any page for the first time will setup the correct 'state'.

Any ideas on how to set this up? I've tried the obvious of always setting `pushState: true` however IE is redirecting to the root and using `#about` whenever visiting `/about`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that using Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, hashChange: false}).